# Как вывести в консоль следующий месяц?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
month = today.strftime("%b")# Показать текущий месяц
print(month)
```

Данный код выводит текущий месяц, в данном случае "Jan"
Как вывести следующий месяц в таком же формате?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import calendar
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
calendar.month_abbr[today.month%12 + 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

t = datetime.date.today()

try:
    n = t.replace(t.year, t.month + 1, 1)
except ValueError:
    n = t.replace(t.year + 1, 1, 1)

print n.strftime("%b")
```

В `n` будет лежать первый день следующего месяца.